# Magento 2.3.3 - Checkout success redirects to cart

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

- Magneto 2.3.3
- File based sessions
- No varnish

We're having a problem after migrating to a new host where around 1/3 orders are successful (can see them in the backend), hit the order success page but are redirected back to their cart with no error. Obviously, for the customer this appears that their order may have failed.

They're redirected due to `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php@execute:23`

```
if (!$this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid()) {
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
}
```

\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator@isValid:

```
public function isValid()
{
    if (!$this->checkoutSession->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->checkoutSession->getLastQuoteId() || !$this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderId()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm logging all order success checkoutSession data and in the instances where customers are redirected, `last_success_quote_id`, `last_quote_id` and `last_order_id` are all `NULL`.

Looking at all the orders there seems to be no pattern differentiating successful vs redirect. There's a mix of payment gateways used (paypal,sagepay) so assuming payment gateway is not the issue here.

I have tried both file and redis based session storage, neither fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar issue to yours before.

The situation was as follows:

1. Site is built on Magento 2.3
2. The payment method is the custom payment method
3. After completion on the external payment gateway, it redirects to cart page other than success page.

I found out the reason using debug.

The problem was that magento didn't provide API with the quote ID of cart.

So I did fix it and the issue was gone away.